# Javascript: How to separate the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am new to JavaScript. Here I am trying to get the item from the array and show this on the browser. But I want `div` to be separated. But here when I am running the program. There is a `div` box for the first object but the second `div` is inside the first `div` box. But I want them to be separated so that I can use some style.

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocPjy.png)

Javascript Code:

```
let menu = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'asos',
        category: 'greece',
        country: 'greece',
        img: './img/Asos.jpg',
        desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda eius animi officiis dolorum eum!'
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        title: 'hamburg',
        category: 'germany',
        country: 'germany',
        img: './img/Hamburg.jpg',
        desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda eius animi officiis dolorum eum!'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: 'heidelberg',
            category: 'germany',
            country: 'germany',
            img: './img/Heidelberg.jpg',
            desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda eius animi officiis dolorum eum!'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            title: 'manarola',
            category: 'italy',
            country: 'italy',
            img: './img/Manarola.jpg',
            desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda eius animi officiis dolorum eum!'
        }
]

let sectionCenter = document.querySelector('.section-center')

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
    let itemMenu = menu.map(function(item) {
        return `             
        <div class="box">
        <img src="${item.img}" class="img" alt="${item.title}">
        <div class="desc">
            <div class="name">
                <h3>${item.title}</h3>
                <h3>${item.country}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="border-bottom"></div>
            <p>${item.desc}</p>
        </div>`
    })
    let displayMenu = itemMenu.join("")
    sectionCenter.innerHTML = displayMenu
})
```

NB: If I use article class='box' instead of div class='box', it works perfectly. But what is the problem of using div??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Also, when you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it, and a toolbar full of formatting aids. They help you format code correctly. No need for all those `<br>`s, etc. (I was fixing it for you, but @Rounin beat me to it. :-) )

Comment: I still have problems making sense of your code. You need to paste the relevant blocks of code into separate sections of the formatting tool i.e. paste HTML in HTML box, CSS in CSS and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing `</div>` tag:

```js
let itemMenu = menu.map(function(item) {
  return `             
    <div class="box">
      <img src="${item.img}" class="img" alt="${item.title}">
      <div class="desc">
          <div class="name">
              <h3>${item.title}</h3>
              <h3>${item.country}</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="border-bottom"></div>
          <p>${item.desc}</p>
      </div>
    </div>`  // <<< Missing tag
})
```